# case when returned result of else no matter what

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have this select query:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (
            SELECT isnull((
                        SELECT max(SeqNo)
                        FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail
                        WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27'
                            AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'
                        ), '0')
            ) = '0'
        THEN (
                SELECT max(SeqNo) + 1
                FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail
                WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27'
                    AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'
                )
    ELSE '1'
    END SeqNo
```

i'm trying to get the rownumber of `SeqNo` based on few conditions, when i select

```
SELECT isnull(SELECT max(SeqNo) FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27')
```

it would give me the result 147 which is right, what i'm trying to do is, if the row exists it would give me the row counts of the second query + 1. which means 147+1 is `148`, and if the row does not exist it would give me the result: `1`

but my query always return `1` and if i remove `then '1'` my query will be resulted `NULL`. where did i do wrong on my query?

Comment: what do you get with this `select isnull((SELECT max(SeqNo) from tblReconBankAccountHODetail where BankAccountID = '0MA27' 
and BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'),'0')` ?

Comment: Seems like you are attempting to create your own auto-increment mechanism. **Don't. This will fail in any multi-user environment.** Sql Server already has a built in identity column - use it.

Comment: @Squirrel the result would be `147`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to get through this by declaring a variable `@counter` that i set into this query

`SELECT ISNULL(MAX(SeqNo), 0) FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27' AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM')`

then putting `@counter` into case when query:

```
CASE WHEN @counter= 0 
 THEN 1   
 ELSE @counter+1  
 END SeqNo
```

shoutout to @Michał Turczyn for a cleaner query

update:

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN (select isnull((SELECT max(SeqNo) from tblReconBankAccountHODetail where BankAccountID = '0MA27' and BusinessDate = @rc),'0')) != 0
            THEN (SELECT max(SeqNo)+1 from tblReconBankAccountHODetail where BankAccountID = '0MA27' and BusinessDate = @rc)
            else 1
    END SeqNo
```

this query above works too

Answer (score 0):

Your query has few problems:

1. SQL syntax uses upper-case, but it's not mnadatory, since it's case insensitive. Use lower or upper-case, but be consistent! Don't mix.
2. Proper indentation greatly simplifies looking at the query (and the code in general) and understanding it.

Here's refactored query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(SeqNo), 0) FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail 
                  WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27' AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM') = 0
            THEN (SELECT MAX(SeqNo) + 1 FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail 
                  WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27' AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM')
            ELSE 1 END SeqNo
```

Your problem was that, you mixed `VARCHAR` datatype with `INT`.

This line:

```
select isnull((SELECT max(SeqNo) from tblReconBankAccountHODetail 
where BankAccountID = '0MA27' and BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'),'0')
```

accordingly to your information, would return always an integer: 147, and then, you compare it to `'0'` which is `CHAR(1)`, thus you get unexpected result.

But, if the inner query returns no rows, query won't work, so I suggest the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail 
                  WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27' AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM') = 0
            THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail 
                  WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27' AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM')
            ELSE 1 END SeqNo
```

or even simplier:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM tblReconBankAccountHODetail 
WHERE BankAccountID = '0MA27' AND BusinessDate = '3/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: still getting the same result which is `1` :(